# PermissionDeniedError while save file toward sub directory in User-managed Notebooks (Vertex AI)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I  develop decision forests ML with the Tensorflow framework by using  User-managed Notebooks on Vertex AI.

Primarily, I have enabled all essential API items
[image]

I cannot save a dataset file  or even a model file on sub-directory on JupyterLab  at all.
Given PermissionDeniedError, I have no idea to tackle this problem.
**PermissionDeniedError: /model; Permission denied**  I created model folder as sub-directory. and I attempt to save the trained model into this directory. but the error is as below.

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as call_get_leaves, _update_step_xla while saving (showing 2 of 2). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionDeniedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/tmp/ipykernel_5762/3506173235.py in <module>
----> 1 model_rf.save("/model")

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_decision_forests/keras/core.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, **kwargs)
   1796 
   1797     super(CoreModel, self).save(
-> 1798         filepath=filepath, overwrite=overwrite, **kwargs)
   1799 
   1800   @staticmethod

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in recursive_create_dir_v2(path)
    511     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    512   """
--> 513   _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    514 
    515 

PermissionDeniedError: /model; Permission denied
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the screenshot. On a Unix-like filesystem, the folder that your arrow is pointing to would probably have path `/smartML-TfTee/model` instead of `/model`. Why are you saving to `/model` instead of `model` or `/smartML-TfTee/model`?

Comment: Hi @PongthornSa, Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?